Rango de valores dentro de un array C++
estoy intentando hacer un programa sencillo de c++, un pirata sobre un matriz de 8x8 que simula ser una isla, dentro de ella encuentra un tesoro. La isla esta rodeada de agua, por lo que si el pirata toca el agua pierde el juego. En la matriz, el agua se localiza en el tope de la matriz, osea, isla[0][1 al 7] osea: isla[fila 0][columnas de 1 a 7]. Mi problema va mas de teoria que no se sobre programar algo en especifico en c++ que del juego en si.
aca mi codigo:
else if(isla[fila_pirata][columna_pirata] == isla[0][/*valores entre 1 y 7*/]){
    printf("\nperdiste el juego\n");
    break;
}

Mi problema, como esta comentado en el codigo, es ese, no se como poner un rango de valores entre 1 y 7 en un array, en esa seccion. Si quisiera hacer un if pirata toca isla[0][1], deberia hacer asi: pirata = isla[0][1] || pirata = isla[0][2] ||... y asi hasta || pirata = isla[0][7], y asi es mucho codigo. Supongo que hay solucion para poner un  rango dentro del array algo asi if pirata == isla[0][1,2,3,4,5,6,7] aunque asi esta mal.
Cualquier respuesta es recibida, gracias

Que contiene la matriz?. Según entiendo de tu descripción, en la matriz tienes que almacenar 3 valores (AGUA, TIERRA y TESORO). Al inicializar la matriz pones la fila de arriba como agua de tal forma que la condición sería if (isla[fila_pirata][_columna_pirata] == AGUA) ...... Entiendo que el pirata se mueve por el mapa (cambiando la fila y columna) hasta encontrar el tesoro o caer al mar. Pero quizás no he entendido correctamente lo que quieres hacer.

Como comenta @RevistaOnlineOccam'sRazor la forma "bonita" de comprobar si el pirata está sobre una casilla de agua sería almacenar en la matriz isla diferentes valores en función del "terreno" de esa casilla, por ejemplo 0 para agua y 1 para tierra (idealmente usa un enum), de este modo podrías simplemente hacer la comprobación isla[fila_pirata][columna_pirata] == 0.
De todos modos si quieres comprobar si se encuentra en ese rango concreto, puedes hacer fila_pirata == 0 && 0 <= columna_pirata && columna_pirata <= 7 (Si columna_pirata no se sale nunca del rango 0-7 no hace falta que hagas las dos últimas comprobaciones y con poner fila_pirata == 0 te valdría).
